# Use C# XmlSerializer to write in chunks for large sets of objects to avoid Out of Memory

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I like how XmlSerialize works, so simple and elegant and with attributes =p  However, I am running into Out of Memory issue while building up a collection of all my objects prior to serializing to xml file.

I am populating an object from a SQL database and intend to write the object out to XML using XmlSerialize.  It works great for small subsets but if I try to grab all the objects from the DB I reach an Out of Memory exception.

Is there some ability of XmlSerialize that would allow me to grab batches of 100 objects out of the database, then write them, grab the next batch of 100 objects and append to the xml?

I am hoping I dont have to bust out into XmlDocument or something that requires more manual coding efforts...

Comment: I think if you should use Database ability to send you record in batches and den wait for next batch. You can even use LINQ to fetch records as you need.

Comment: @GauravSharma Yes, agreed.  But Im not sure that "appending" to existing file is something that is supported by XmlSerializer in C# ?

Comment: HI Kairan, I am not sure about appending functionality of XmlSerializer. Even if do, it will be prone to Memory Out of exception in case of very big file. You should think of finding out the max size of a file that don't time out and then start creating a new file. Similar to what logging frameworks like Log4Net do.

Comment: You only need to serialize, and not deserialize, right?

Comment: This may not be relevant for your situation, but I can remember that I had several serious problems with the built-in .Net XML serializer some 3-4 years ago when I tried to use it. I ended up dropping it. There are alternative serializer packages available, maybe that's what you should be looking into.

Comment: Do you have the ability to write an `IEnumerable<T>` which grabs data in chunks from the database?  I assume you do.

Comment: @dbc I will need to read it back in later to put the data back into the database ... think of it as import/exporting of the database into an xml format

Comment: @dbc Its essentially a Movie/TV database, I have already got a loop that is populating each movie and tv from multiple tables so that is where I can itereate

Comment: If you need to read the XML file back in, won't you run out of memory at that point, even if you didn't run out of memory serializing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` can, in fact, stream enumerable data in and out when serializing.  It has special handling for a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The XmlSerializer gives special treatment to classes that implement IEnumerable or ICollection. A class that implements IEnumerable must implement a public Add method that takes a single parameter. The Add method's parameter must be of the same type as is returned from the Current property on the value returned from GetEnumerator, or one of that type's bases.

When serializing such classes, `XmlSerializer` simply iterates through the enumerable writing each current value to the output stream.  It *does not* load the entire enumerable into a list first.  Thus, if you have some Linq query that dynamically pages in results of type `T` from a database in chunks (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260419/handling-large-sql-queries-with-linq)), you can serialize all of them out without loading them all at once using the following wrapper:

```
// Proxy class for any enumerable with the requisite `Add` methods.
public class EnumerableProxy<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<T> BaseEnumerable { get; set; }

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (BaseEnumerable == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();
        return BaseEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note this class is only useful for serializing, not deserializing.  Here is an example of how to use it:

```
public class RootObject<T>
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<T> Results { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Results")]
    public EnumerableProxy<T> ResultsProxy { 
        get
        {
            return new EnumerableProxy<T> { BaseEnumerable = Results };
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    XmlWriter xmlWriter;
    TextWriter textWriter;

    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            var root = new RootObject<int>();
            root.Results = GetResults();

            using (textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "  " };
                using (xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                {
                    (new XmlSerializer(root.GetType())).Serialize(xmlWriter, root);
                }
                var xml = textWriter.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine(xml);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            xmlWriter = null;
            textWriter = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<int> GetResults()
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000))
        {
            if (i > 0 && (i % 500) == 0)
            {
                HalfwayPoint();
            }
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    private void HalfwayPoint()
    {
        if (xmlWriter != null)
        {
            xmlWriter.Flush();
            var xml = textWriter.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

If you set a break in `HalfwayPoint()`, you will see that half the XML has already been written out while still iterating through the enumerable.  (Of course, I'm just writing to a string for test purposes while you would probably be writing to a file.)