# Formulate a well-formed xml from Xml fragments using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I am formulating xmlnodes from a loop. so what it does is

```
   var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
   settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
   settings.Indent = true;
   var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   ns.Add("", "");
   foreach (Person human in bar)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Append))
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, human, ns);
        }
    }
```

It formulates xml fragments when the loop is done the output XML is like this

```
    <Person>
  <Name>mar8a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar1a</Name>
  <Age>1</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar2a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar3a</Name>
  <Age>1</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person><Person>
  <Name>mar4a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar5a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar6a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar7a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>mar8a</Name>
  <Age>11</Age>
  <Sex>MALE</Sex>
  <Address>TOP 92 BOTTOM</Address>
  <SingleYn>false</SingleYn>
</Person>
```

the problem i am running thru is how to modify it and make it a a well formed xml with root node and declaration at the end of the loop.

ive tried the following concept but no luck on it for it restricts me to write no root elements on the writer.

```
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        XmlReaderSettings ws = new XmlReaderSettings();
        ws.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        String xmlString =
                @"<Item>test with a child element stuff</Item>
                <Item>test with a child element stuff</Item>";
        // Create an XmlReader
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString), ws))
        {
            XmlWriterSettings ws2 = new XmlWriterSettings();
            ws2.Indent = true;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws2))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                            writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                            writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

            }
        }
```

**Update!!**

here is the code that serialize a list my implementation of serializer

```
        public static async Task WriteXMLAsync<T>(this List<T> listRows, T entity, VMEXPORT[] arrVmExport, string filePath)
        where T : class
    {
        XmlWriterSettings Xmlsettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        Xmlsettings.Indent = true;
        Xmlsettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
        Xmlsettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
        Xmlsettings.Async = true;
        Xmlsettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Xmlsettings.CheckCharacters = false;

        XmlAttributeOverrides Xmloverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes Xmlattribs = new XmlAttributes();
        Xmlattribs.XmlIgnore = true;
        Xmlattribs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("SfiObjectState"));
        Xmloverrides.Add(typeof(T), "SfiObjectState", Xmlattribs);


        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, true))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), Xmloverrides);
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, Xmlsettings))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, listRows);
                    await xmlWriter.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, true))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), Xmloverrides);
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, Xmlsettings))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, listRows);
                    await xmlWriter.FlushAsync();
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

**And heres what iterates on the method above implementing take and skip**

```
 public async Task WriteXmlDataAsync<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> listToWrite, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest dataRequest,
                                          int countno, VMEXPORT[] vmExportarr, CancellationToken token,
                                          TEntity entity, string csvFileNametx, string XmlFilePathtx)
      where TEntity : class
    {
        dataRequest.GroupingToSorting();
        int datapageno = (countno / GeneralConst.L_MAX_EXPORT_REC) + 1;
        for (int ctrno = 1; ctrno <= datapageno; )
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                RemoveTask(csvFileNametx);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            dataRequest.Page = ctrno;
            dataRequest.PageSize = GeneralConst.L_MAX_EXPORT_REC;
            var dataSourceResult = listToWrite.ToDataSourceResult(dataRequest);
            await dataSourceResult.Data.Cast<TEntity>().ToList().WriteXMLAsync(entity, vmExportarr, XmlFilePathtx);
            ctrno = ctrno + 1;
            int percentageno = (ctrno * 100) / datapageno;
            if (percentageno > 100) percentageno = 100;
            UpdateTask(csvFileNametx, percentageno);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can't you just write whole list to XML (may need to add wrapper class to have root element you like)?

Comment: i need to append the xml fragments in batch. (scalability concerns) making the fragments in a asynchronous way to append couple of hundreds of records in turn. if i write the whole list in my scenario it will have multiple root elements

Comment: XML is probably not the best format for data you trying to save than... Anyway your sample does not write root node of any kind (`WriteStartDocument` does not magically create root node for you).

Comment: thanks for that clarification.. I managed to do it in a csv file. I cant create the whole List<bar> into xml using XmlSerializer class but the problem is when i append another thats another well formed xml so what happen is there will be many root elements. Any other suggestion @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: If you can't load all items in the list of people at once, you can use `XmlSerializer` to stream out the entire list in demand-loaded chunks.  See here for an example of how to do it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837438/use-c-sharp-xmlserializer-to-write-in-chunks-for-large-sets-of-objects-to-avoid

Comment: i cant even figure out how would you implement that way. does it means you're feeding the serializer in chunks??

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You wrote, "i need to append the xml fragments in batch".  So, you have some method to generate lists of your `Person` class in chunks, that you call multiple times, right?  What does it look like?

Comment: i wil put the entire code. I'll update

Comment: @dbc that is my implementation of the serializer. i call it in a loop to append the file but as it loops it appends multiple root because of the serializer, i think its doable if got thru your implementation but how would my loop use just only one serializer feeding up from the loop??

Comment: I see, you're doing the work with many `async/await` units.  That doesn't fit with my previous solution which demand-loads the list contents from within `XmlSerializer`.  Would it be possible to do the entire operation in one big task?

Comment: You previously mentioned "scalability concerns".  Does that mean that, after writing the list, it's too big to load back into memory?

Comment: yeah something like that. in my case right now its 5millions of records and 1.68gb of xml files when indented and 1.2 if not.. by the way its a web app. one big task can be. we can wrapped it up in an async or background worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You could do something quick and dirty like this after the XML file is written:

```
    public static void AddOuterElement(string fileName, string elementName)
    {
        var startElement = string.Format(@"<{0}>", elementName);
        var endElement = string.Format(@"</{0}>", elementName);

        var tmpName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        try
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tmpName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(startElement);
                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))  // Reads lines incrementally rather than all at once.
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                writer.WriteLine(endElement);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(tmpName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            throw;
        }
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        System.IO.File.Move(tmpName, fileName);
    }
```

This requires writing the XML file twice.

**Option 2**

Assume you have some method that can return lists of your `Person` class in chunks, say with the following signature:

```
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPeopleInChunks()
    {
        // Query the database in chunks of 200 and yield return each list.
    }
```

Then you could use the following classes adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838727/3744182) to serialize all the people in the database sequentially without ever loading them all into memory at once:

```
// Proxy class for any enumerable with the requisite `Add` methods.
public class EnumerableProxy<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<T> BaseEnumerable { get; set; }

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (BaseEnumerable == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();
        return BaseEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}

[XmlRoot("People")]
public class People
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Results { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Person")]
    public EnumerableProxy<Person> ResultsProxy
    {
        get
        {
            return new EnumerableProxy<Person> { BaseEnumerable = Results };
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
    public void WriteXml(string fileName)
    {
        var people = new People { Results = GetPeopleInChunks().SelectMany(chunk => chunk) };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName))
        {
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(People)).Serialize(writer, people);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this looks good. the yeild will eventually should work. what i had in mind i should do it like this is the amount of data to avoid oom exception.. this feeds the serializer per yeild of the getchunks right??

Comment: @EduCielo - "this feeds the serializer per yeild of the getchunks right" - exactly.  And the `SelectMany` makes it look like a single enumerable rather than a bunch of chunks.

Comment: explained here the cleaner way than way in your answer to the other post.. This makes the Xmlserializer more slick..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.  You also need to have only one level of tags at root level.

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);


            XmlDeclaration xDeclare = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

            doc.InsertBefore(xDeclare, doc.FirstChild);

            //or
            string xml1 ="<Root>" + "Your XML" + "</Root>";

            //or
            string xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root>" + "Your XML" + "</Root>"; 
​
```

Comment: yeah in that approach i have written the file a "huge" xml file then load it up as string then append it in to close the tags. I guess it will not be a better idea

Comment: Write the declaration and root tag at beginning of file.  Then write you huge data to the file.  Finally write closing tag before closing file.  This way you don't have to open, read and write huge file 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your Person nodes are in a string of some description, an easy way to turn that into a document would be something like this:

```
    XmlDocument oXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""));

    string sFileContents = "XML Fragments In Here";

    XmlNode oRootXmlNode = oXmlDocument.CreateElement("Root");
    oRootXmlNode.InnerXml = sFileContents;

    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oRootXmlNode);
    oXmlDocument.Save("XMLFileName.xml");
```

This might not be a good idea if the fragments end up being enormous.