# Most efficient Entity Framework XML serialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

You can serialize the contents of a DB table with the following code:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities()) {
    var all = db.MyTable.AsQueryable();
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path)) {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(all.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, all);
    }
}
```

However, this creates an "ugly" XML file with many unneeded attributes.

You can also do this to create a prettier XML file (but still a lot of `xmlns` in the header, though):

```
using (var db = new MyEntities()) {
    var all = db.MyTable.ToList();
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path)) {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(all.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, all);
    }
}
```

`AsQueryable` doesn't work with XmlSerializer, so you have to use `.ToList()`. This reads the entire table into memory, though, which is not very efficient for large datasets.

So the questions is: How can I create a "clean" XML file from a table using Entity Framework (Database First) the most efficiently (without having to read everything into memory)?

Bonus question: How would you serialize only certain columns from the table? Using `.Select(t => new { t.Column1, T.Column2 }=)` doesn't work because an anonymous type doesn't have a parameterless contructor.

Comment: There's no difference in the EF code in the two snippets. The real difference is that they are using completely different serializers. BTW you *don't* need to use `AsQueryable()` if `db` is a `DbContext` and `MyTable` a DbSet. It's an IQueryable already

Comment: `XmlSerializer` can't work with `DbSet` because `DbSet` doesn't have an `Add()` method.

Comment: No serializer works with DbSet. DbSet isn't a container, it's a class that implements IQueryable<T>. IQueryable represents a *query*. It has to be executed in order to retrieve results. Whether you do that by calling `.ToList()` or casting it to `IEnumerable<T>` explicitly, or implicitly with a `foreach`, the result is the same - the query is executed and you get back the results. That's why the only real difference in the two snippets is the serializer

Comment: If you want to serialize an `IEnumerable<T>` without loading the entire thing into memory, you can wrap it in an explicitly typed wrapper implementing  `ICollection<T>` with a dummy `Add()` method, as shown in e.g. [Use C# XmlSerializer to write in chunks for large sets of objects to avoid Out of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838727).